# No autofit for plotly scatter text element

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create heatmap using squares and labels (I will need to customize it in a special way, so I cannot use heatmap directly). There is a problem, however, that the text is cut.

[image: Example]

Is there a way to fix it, so that the graph autofits the text?

Here goes the code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate value
values = np.random.random((5, 10))

# initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()

# fill figure
for i, row in enumerate(values):
    max_val = row.max()
    
    # add text for the row
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[-0.2],
        y=[i + 0.5],
        text=['MY TEXT'],
        mode="text",
        textposition="middle left"
    ))
    
    # add square for each value in a row
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                            x=[j,j,j+1,j+1,j], 
                            y=[i,i+1,i+1,i,i], 
                            fill="toself",
                            mode='lines',
                            fillcolor='blue',
                            line=dict(width=0),
                            opacity=val/max_val
                        ))

# figure layout
fig.update_layout(
    height=400,
    width=600,
    showlegend=False,
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this is to use **annotations** instead of *mode="text"* for **go.Scatter**.

```
fig.add_annotation(
    x=-0.2, 
    y=i+0.5,
    text='MY TEXT',
    xanchor="right",
    valign="middle",
    showarrow=False
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is that there is not enough space in the increments that the graph is increasing by on the x-axis and I have came up with two solutions.

One of the solutions is simply increasing the width. Which can be done by:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate value
values = np.random.random((5, 10))

# initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()

# fill figure
for i, row in enumerate(values):
    max_val = row.max()
    
    # add text for the row
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[-0.2],
        y=[i + 0.5],
        text=['MY TEXT'],
        mode="text",
        textposition="middle left"
    ))
    
    # add square for each value in a row
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                            x=[j,j,j+1,j+1,j], 
                            y=[i,i+1,i+1,i,i], 
                            fill="toself",
                            mode='lines',
                            fillcolor='blue',
                            line=dict(width=0),
                            opacity=val/max_val
                        ))

# figure layout
fig.update_layout(
    height=400,
    width=1200,
    showlegend=False,
)

fig.show()
```

The other is setting the cliponaxis to false which looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate value
values = np.random.random((5, 10))

# initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()

# fill figure
for i, row in enumerate(values):
    max_val = row.max()
    
    # add text for the row
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[-0.2],
        y=[i + 0.5],
        text=['MY TEXT'],
        cliponaxis=False,
        mode="text",
        textposition="middle left"
    ))
    
    # add square for each value in a row
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                            x=[j,j,j+1,j+1,j], 
                            y=[i,i+1,i+1,i,i], 
                            fill="toself",
                            mode='lines',
                            fillcolor='blue',
                            line=dict(width=0),
                            opacity=val/max_val
                        ))

# figure layout
fig.update_layout(
    height=400,
    width=600,
    showlegend=False,
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I am just wondering, if there is a solutions, which can automatically adjust, because I need a compact chart, labels can be of different length and the margins can reduced.

Comment: I was thinking that another possible solution could be decreasing the text size, but I felt that solution would look a bit weird. I do not  believe that there is a solution that allows it to automatically adjust, based on the reading I did while trying to figure out a solution